# My iPad Air won't open internet pages on Safari

Tags: ipad, wifi, safari

I have two devices that are both connected to the *same Wi-Fi* at my house.

We use wireless network and for the past two days I've been getting this message whenever I tried to go on the Internet and search things like "google" or "twitter" or anything else it just doesn't work at all.

And I'm surprised because it only do that to my iPad and not my iPod since I have two devices.

It sends me this message saying:

> `There was a problem communicating with the secure web proxy server
>   (HTTPS)`

and I honestly don't know what it means and how to fix it.

I tried everything else I read and saw online still nothing worked!

I'm getting very worried now because it a brand new iPad, and it's been doing this for two days now! Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try to Reset the Safari ?

Comment: Is work other wifi network? Example: Starbucks or friend house?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed an app called "Onavo" ?? If it is no longer working with your  network then you may face such issues..

First, try resetting your cellular data network settings..

Settings-->general-->network -->cellular data network --> reset

Secondly, remove any configuration profiles..

Settings --> General --> Profiles -->"name of profile" -->click remove profile

Now finally try opening a web page and see whether it works..